# Google redirect failing on symfony website

Tags: domain-name-system, .htaccess, hacking, google, symfony

I am helping a friend with her website mainteinance and there is some strange behaviour that I do not fully understand.

When you search for her site on google.com, and click on her main website, the website has a redirect to google.com. If I copy and paste the same hyperlink and type it directly on the browser, it works fine.

- I have reviewed .htaccess and it seems to be fine
- Also checked a curl and traceroute seem to be okey
- Checked dns
- Checked the google console and everything seems fine, except when opening the link in a new tab

Here is the search https://www.google.com/search?q=lara+padilla&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS812US812&oq=lara+padi&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l3j69i61l3.1411j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 where you can find the broken link at "Sra. D el alter ego de Lara Padilla" (not working)

And here is the link from the search https://srad.wtf/ (working if you just copy paste)

I feel completely lost, so any help will be invaluable, thanks

Comment: I see this behavior only on the home page. It is probably a server misconfiguration. Please provide the relevant web server configuration.

Comment: There are two different .htaccess. Here is one under  {www_public} https://pastebin.com/yJncCXrD and there is a second one in a subfolder called {www_public}/public https://pastebin.com/z3kKk3uN

Answer (score 1):

It's not just Google. The site appears to be 302 redirecting back to the HTTP `Referer` when performing the "language" redirect.

When requesting the document root *only* you appear to be performing a (unconditional?) language (302) redirect to `/es_ES/`. However, when the HTTP `Referer` header is passed then you are redirecting back to the *full* `Referer` instead!?

Regarding the link in the question... ServerFault has a `referrer-policy: no-referrer` policy on outbound links so no `Referer` header is sent and no erroneous redirect occurs.

*Aside:* Language redirects are generally a bad idea for SEO and user experience since they are notoriously prone to error. The site in question appears to be *unconditionally* redirecting to `/es_ES/` (Spanish), despite there being other (more relevant for *me*) language version(s) available, eg. `/en/` (English).

Comment: Hi @mrwhite, could you please check the links with the .htaccess files? To be honest, I am not even sure about why there are two files instead of just one.

Comment: Any updates on this? Thank you